# Remove clickable Link of Wordpress Site Logo from Woocommerce Single Product page

Tags: functions, woocommerce-offtopic, css

I need help to remove clickable Link of Wordpress Site Logo from Woocommerce Single Product page. i tried following css code

```
.home .site-logo a { pointer-events: none; }
```

and it works for Homepage. But i need to avoid users going to home page when they come to woocommerce single product page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each product should have a unique class identifier in the body. Compare two product pages and depending on the theme you are using. Allot of them have a unique css identify.

Look for something like: postid- followed my numbers for example.

If you had something like:

```
<body class="product-template-default single single-product postid-3592 wp-custom-logo woocommerce woocommerce-page woocommerce-no-js shop-buttons-is-sticky">
```

Then you could target it using the postid-3592 class as its unique to that product page.

So you could do:

```
.postid-3592 .site-logo a { pointer-events: none !important; }
```

**or for all products using a single product template you could use:**

```
.single-product .site-logo a { pointer-events: none !important; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. after reading your comment i tried to remove it and following CSS code worked. thanks a lot for suggestion. without that i wouldn't have found this

a.custom-logo-link{ pointer-events: none !important; }

span.site-title{ pointer-events: none; }

Comment: That's great to hear. Not a problem. Please accept the answer if it solved your issue  :)